# Get Coordinates of NMAMapMarker

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api, here-ios

I am working with Here Maps offline maps. I had added four MapMarkers
(annotations) . Now i want to get the NMAGeoCoordinates of the Map marker using the didSelectObjects:(NSArray *)objects method. This method returns the values, but it does not return the coordinates of the MapMarker.. 
Please guide me how to get the coordinates of the marker on selecting it. 
Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didSelectObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{  
NSArray * arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:objects.lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
}
```

Comment: What kind of `objects` are returned? It's returning a array of array?

Comment: It returns array with object of NMAMapmarker class and contains various attributes but there is no location coordiantes in it. I want to know the coordinates of the selected marker

Comment: When you cast the Object inside didSelectObjects listner into NMAMapmarker, what is the value in coordinates ?

Comment: Thanks .. I found the solution...

Comment: -(void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didSelectObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
        [self getlocation];
        NMAMapMarker * marker=objects.lastObject;
        NSLog(@"%@",marker.location);
        _DestinationCoordinate=marker.location;
        [self CalculateRoute];
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)mapView:(NMAMapView *)mapView didSelectObjects:(NSArray *)objects {  

    NMAMapMarker *mapMarker = objects.firstObject;
    NSLog(@"coordinates: %@",mapMarker.coordinates);
}
```

Comment: one more thing i have NMA mapview and its delegate methods in a seperate viewcontroller and load it inside the viewcontroller in which map is required. Map markers are added but when i try to select the markers mapView didSelectObjects: method is not called. Help me @Burhanuddin Sunelwala

Comment: @Mohanraj did you set the delegate to the viewcontroller? `mapView.delegate = self;`

Comment: how to use this in swift??

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala NMAMapMarker *mapMarker = objects.firstObject;   from mapMarker how to get title name

Comment: Please check my question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848113/tap-on-particular-marker-how-to-get-title-name